# Button in ListBox item's ItemsControl doesn't fire in WPF XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding, listbox

I've got the following setup for my `ListBox` in wpf:

- `ListBox` with as `ItemsPanel` a `StackPanel` (orientation horizontal)
- `ItemTemplate` of `ListBox` is a `Grid` with a `TextBox` and an `ItemsControl`
- the Items control contains buttons with as `ItemPanel` a `WrapPanel`.

Somehow when I click on one of the buttons in the `ItemsPanel`, the `ICommand` wont fire in the ViewModel class which is bound to the View.xaml.
It looks like I'm selecting the `ListBox` item and not the item within the `ItemsControl`.

Here's the xaml code

```
<ListBox 
   Background="Transparent" 
   ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ProductGroupTemplate}" 
   FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" 
   VerticalContentAlignment="Top" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding NodeHeaders}" 
   Grid.Row="1" 
   Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
   Grid.Column="0" 
   Grid.RowSpan="2" 
   SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentItem}" 
   BorderBrush="Transparent" 
   ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
   ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
   Margin="30,0,55,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top">
   <ListBox.Style>
      <Style TargetType="ListBox">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasParent}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.Style>
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

And the DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ProductGroupTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,20,0">          
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{StaticResource DefaultLabelColor}" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical"  IsItemsHost="True"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Description}" Height="75" Width="150" Padding="5" Margin="5" Background="{StaticResource SalesItemsBackground}" 
                                Foreground="{StaticResource SalesItemsForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" Command="{Binding RelativeSource=
        {RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
        AncestorType={x:Type ContentControl}}, 
        Path=DataContext.Select}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a view model that declares an `ICommand` instance and is set as the `DataContext` of a view (`UserControl`, or `Window`), then you can use that property to access your `ICommand` instance. From the `Button` in your `DataTemplate`, you can use this `RelativeSource Binding`:

```
<Button Text="{Binding Description}" Height="75" Width="150" Padding="5" Margin="5" 
    Background="{StaticResource SalesItemsBackground}" TextAlignment="Left" 
    Foreground="{StaticResource SalesItemsForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center" Command="{Binding DataContext.Select, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourViewsPrefix:YourView}}}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because your data template's DataContext is set to an item from the listbox. If you have List<Person> bound to your list box every list box item's DataContext would be a Person which is why you can write something like "{Binding Description}". You have two ways to execute a command from DataTemplate one of them is the one that "Sheridan" told you. As an alternative you could set your element's DataContext to your parent View or ViewModel.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type View/ViewModel}}">
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```